# How to use server side pagination if i have multiple queries and want to display the result in table?

Tags: php, datatables, server-side-rendering

I have large database data , and I am querying from different tables and want to get results in different arrays after calculations then I want to combine the data and display that in one table ?

Something like that;

```
$query = select everything from table one ;
$query2 = select userid from $query result;

<?php print Calculation ;?>

$resultant query = select something from another table where date from the above result and userid from $queryone array;
```

Display in data tables with server side processing ???

Appreciate if anybody help

Comment: Why not handle it in the database itself and send only the expected output to php?

Comment: Can you post your schema DDL and which database system you're using? It looks like you can achieve the result from one statement with a sub-query, `select something from another table where userid = (SELECT userid from table1)` use the LIMIT clause if MySQL or TOP if MSSQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use database query with JOIN in server-side processing mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32908788/how-to-use-database-query-with-join-in-server-side-processing-mode)

Comment: @Gyrocode.com no the problem is that i am pivoting data from different arrays into matrix type, thats why i use to get employee data in one query and get operational data in another query then i put all the two arrays data and display one array x-axis and other array  horizontally  against each user .

Comment: if just want to know how to do it with multi queries, the solution i provided is perfect but slow that's why i supposed to go for server side paging... any help will be appreciate ..